# AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'extract_first'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to run the script below to extract the tags from a webpage and save them into a csv file.

In details, I want to extract the tags associated to a class name.

However, I come across this error: AttributeError:

```
'WebElement' object has no attribute 'extract_first'.
```

The script is the following:

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from parsel import Selector
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from collections import defaultdict
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

####### reading from the input file ##########

columns = defaultdict(list)  # each value in each column is appended to a list

# get the list of keywords from the csv file
with open('query.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)  # read rows into a dictionary format
for row in reader:  # read a row as {column1: value1, column2: value2,...}
    for (k, v) in row.items():  # go over each column name and value
        columns[k].append(v)  # append the value into the appropriate list

# the list containing all of the keywords
search_query_list = columns['Keyword']

########## start scraping ###############

rb_results = []

# create a driver and let it open google chrome
driver = webdriver.Chrome("chromedriver")

# get website
driver.get('https://www.redbubble.com/')
sleep(0.5)

for i in range(len(search_query_list)):

next_query = search_query_list[i]

# get RB website
driver.get('https://www.redbubble.com/')

# get the search by its id
search_bar = driver.find_element_by_name("query")

sleep(0.5)

# enter the query to the search bar
search_bar.send_keys(next_query)

# press enter
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
sleep(1)


# from parsel's selector get the page source
sel1 = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
sleep(0.5)

# get first shirt //
continue_link = driver.find_element_by_class_name('shared-components-ShopSearchSkeleton-ShopSearchSkeleton__composedComponentWrapper--1s_CI').click()
sleep(1)

sel2 = Selector(text=driver.page_source)
sleep(0.5)

################## get TAGS ###############

# Check tags for all products
try:
    # get the tags for the search query   
    tags_rb = driver.find_element_by_class_name("shared-components-Tags-Tags__listContent--oLdDf").extract_first()
    tags_rb = str(tags_rb)
       # if number of products is found print it and search for the prime
    # print the number of products found
    if tags_rb == None:
        rb_results.append("0")

    else:

        #rb_results = str(tags_rb)
        rb_results.append(tags_rb)

except ValueError:
   pass

#except:
 #rb_results.append("errore")   

###### writing part ########
with open ("rb_results.csv","w", newline='') as resultFile: 
    writer = csv.DictWriter(resultFile, fieldnames=["Rb Results"],delimiter='\t')
    writer.writeheader()

    writer.writerows({'Rb Results': item} for item in rb_results)

    resultFile.close()
```

Any ideas about how to fix it and extract the text of `shared-components-Tags-Tags__listContent--oLdDf` ? Many thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I right understand, you want an element text. So you can do it like this:

replace:

```
tags_rb = driver.find_element_by_class_name("shared-components-Tags-Tags__listContent--oLdDf").extract_first()
```

with:

```
tags_rb = driver.find_element_by_class_name("shared-components-Tags-Tags__listContent--oLdDf").text
```

You are getting this error:

```
'WebElement' object has no attribute 'extract_first'.
```

because `WebElement` does not have method `.extract_first()`.

***PS:*** you don't need this:

```
tags_rb = str(tags_rb)
```

The code block to replace is:

```
# Check tags for all products
try:
    # get the tags for the search query   
    tags_rb = driver.find_element_by_class_name("shared-components-Tags-Tags__listContent--oLdDf").text # get text
    # tags_rb = str(tags_rb) no need in this line
       # if number of products is found print it and search for the prime
    # print the number of products found
    if tags_rb == None:
        rb_results.append("0")

    else:

        #rb_results = str(tags_rb)
        rb_results.append(tags_rb)

except ValueError:
   pass
```

Comment: did you able to find web element with this locator `shared-components-Tags-Tags__listContent--oLdDf`

Comment: thank you so much indeed!!!! it was because I wanted to extract the text: thanks to your hint it works!

Comment: @Stefano then you can mark my answer by clicking on the grey check button below downvote button, if you are satisfied with my help ;)

Comment: @cruisepandey Hi! I didn't test the whole code. So I don't know if OP using right selectors.

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov : I was trying with his locator , but I think he has written a wrong one. I believe `.text` was good catch.